# Open iframe in a new window

Tags: html, iframe

How do I open an iframe in a new window? I tried with "scrolling='auto'". It did not work.

I put my code here:

```
<iframe width="572px" scrolling="auto" height="335px" 
        frameborder="1" src="http://XXXX.com/iframe-page"
        style="border: 0px none #ffffff;" name="national-campaign" 
        marginheight="0px" marginwidth="0px">
</iframe>
```

I want to open a link in a new window. I have two sites, a corporate site and a dealer site. On the corporate site, I have a page with only an image that I want to display in both corporate site and dealer site. When you click on the image, it goes to view detail page. However, what I want in my dealer site is, when you click on the iframe image, it opens the tab in a new window, instead of displaying detail page inside the iframe.

Any ideas? Cheers.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what you mean by that? Do you want to open a link in a new window? An iframe is a "window" embedded in another page. Without that other page the concept of embedding, and hence iframe, doesn't seem to make much sense.

Comment: You can't unless both pages are on the same domain.

Comment: Yes, I want to open a link in a new window. I have two sites, a corporate site and a dealer site. On the corporate site, I have a page with only an image that I want to display in both corporate site and dealer site. When you click on the image, it goes to view detail page. However, what I want in my dealer site is, when you click on the iframe image, it opens the tab in a new window, instead of displaying detail page inside the iframe. Hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 6):

You can do it with jquery and window.open method.

HTML:

```
<iframe id="iframe" width="572px" scrolling="auto" height="335px" 
        frameborder="1" src="http://XXXX.com/iframe-page"
        style="border: 0px none #ffffff;" name="national-campaign" 
        marginheight="0px" marginwidth="0px">
</iframe>
```

JS :

```
var iframe = $("#iframe"); 
var newWindow = window.open(iframe.attr(src), 'Dynamic Popup', 'height=' + iframe.height() + ', width=' + iframe.width() + 'scrollbars=auto, resizable=no, location=no, status=no');
newWindow.document.write(iframe[0].outerHTML);
newWindow.document.close();
iframe[0].outerHTML = ''; // to remove iframe in page.
```

Comment: What you suggest is simple js - which would not be available to you on the parent window - unless the parent domain had no restrictions on your iframe's js capability, which would be unlikely.

Answer (score 2):

Try to add `target="_top"` inside that link.

or alternatively if you need to open a new page from a link inside an iframe if i understood correctly you can:

Using **jQuery**:

```
$('iframe a').attr('target', '_blank');
```

Answer (score 1):

The easy way is to use a hyperlink with an attribute target="_blank".

If the height and width are important to you (cf. your example), then you can use the JavaScript method [window.open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.open).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you just use a hyperlink to another page rather than an iframe. Or a screenshot image that is actually a link.

Some users may be 'smart' enough to right-click within the iframe (in internet explorer) and select a 'open in new window' option, but others wouldn't do that.

Comment: Hi, I finally made it worked using 'target="_top"' on the corporate site image. So the code is: <a href="/details-page" target="_top"><img src="/images/image.jpg" /></a>.

Comment: Or 'target=_blank" to open a new window :)

Comment: but this is done using a hyperlink and not the iframe